# Assign Label value if same as given list in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, label

Here supposed my dataframe is here,

[image]

When comparing a column in a dataframe with a list that I have, I want to label the rows in that column if they have the same value. 
for example compare with 'Name' and my 'list'(ex) list = [Y,B]

so In 'Name' Column have [Y,B] -> Labeled '0'

[image]

How Can I make this code having above condition?

(*The list length is very shorter than other column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('KYBBC')})
L = ['Y','B']
df['Label'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(L), '0', '')

print (df)
  Name Label
0    K      
1    Y     0
2    B     0
3    B     0
4    C
```

Comment: Can you put the list name? ex) List name is YB = [Y,B....] cause list is longer than my in example

Comment: The `L` is the code `df['Name'].isin(L)` refer to the list you have. It doesn't matter how long it is.

Comment: umm. I got an error ,, this ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @ybin - With real real data was changed `'0', ''` ?

Comment: Yes all condition is same. change to '0', It just big dataframe than my example..

Comment: @ybin - Added sample data and working nice, are data confidental? Because if not working it seems some dat arelated problem.

Comment: @jezrael I added my data example and code , but it is a privacy data , so after solving problem and I deleted real data sample.. Thank you!

Comment: @jezrael I have two simliar dataset, one is working but the second(above) isn`t..

Comment: @ybin - hmmm, if filter non working dataframe for first 10 rows only like `df = df.head(10)` and test solution it working?

Comment: Now I can’t test it. After trying that and notice you! Thank you